# Unable to select date from date picker in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, datepicker

```
package newpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\downloads\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");

        try {
            String fname="abc";
            String lname="xyz";
            String email="abcxyz@gmail.com";
            driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys(fname);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).sendKeys(lname);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("userEmail")).sendKeys(email);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gender-radio-1"));
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("userNumber")).sendKeys("909876765");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            String date ="13-August-2019";
            String dateArr[]= date.split("-");
            String day=dateArr[0];
            String month=dateArr[1];
            String year=dateArr[2];
            driver.findElement(By.id("dateOfBirthInput")).click();
            Select selectMonth =new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dateOfBirth\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/select")));
            //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dateOfBirth\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]")).getText());
            selectMonth.selectByVisibleText(month);
            Select selectYear=new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("react-datepicker__year-select")));
            selectYear.selectByVisibleText(year);       
            String beforePath="//*[@id=\"dateOfBirth\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[";
            String afterPath="]/div[";
            boolean flag=false;
            for (int row =1 ;row <=6; row++) {
                for (int col =1; col<=7; col++) {
                    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(beforePath+row+afterPath+col+"]")).getText());
                    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(beforePath+row+afterPath+col+"]")).getText().equals(day)) {
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath(beforePath+row+afterPath+col+"]")).click()
                        flag=true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(flag)
                        break;
                }
            }
            
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("subjectsInput")).sendKeys("English");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).submit();           
                
        }
        finally{
            
            
            driver.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Link of for used for avove code : https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form

I get following error :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 31214
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Aug 06, 2020 7:22:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
************************
*************************************************************
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="dateOfBirth"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]"}
 (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-E926NDJ', ip: '192.168.178.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 84.0.4147.105, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\T...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64230}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: dd62b7398d8b7df16f67bd9ccedc36d4
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id="dateOfBirth"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]}
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
   at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
   at newpackage.Example.main(Example.java:68)
```

I am not able to select the date

Error i am facing is : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="dateOfBirth"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem, please use the following code to fix it -

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");

try {
  String fname = "abc";
  String lname = "xyz";
  String email = "abcxyz@gmail.com";
  driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys(fname);
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).sendKeys(lname);
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  driver.findElement(By.id("userEmail")).sendKeys(email);
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gender-radio-1"));
  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  driver.findElement(By.id("userNumber")).sendKeys("909876765");
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  String date = "13-August-2019";
  String dateArr[] = date.split("-");
  String day = dateArr[0];
  String month = dateArr[1];
  String year = dateArr[2];
  driver.findElement(By.id("dateOfBirthInput")).click();
  Select selectMonth = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dateOfBirth\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/select")));
  // System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dateOfBirth\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]")).getText());
  selectMonth.selectByVisibleText(month);
  Select selectYear = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("react-datepicker__year-select")));
  selectYear.selectByVisibleText(year);
  String beforePath = "//div[@id='dateOfBirth']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[";
  String afterPath = "]/div[";
  boolean flag = false;

  for (int row = 1; row <= 6; row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= 7; col++) {
      System.out.println("Row: " + row);
      System.out.println("Col: " + col);
      System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(beforePath + row + afterPath + col + "]")).getText());
      if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(beforePath + row + afterPath + col + "]")).getText().equals(day)) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(beforePath + row + afterPath + col + "]")).click();
        flag = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (flag)
      break;
  }

  Thread.sleep(1000);
  driver.findElement(By.id("subjectsInput")).sendKeys("English");
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).submit();

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

finally {
  driver.close();
}
```

}

Problem was with the placement of `break` statement for the 2nd for loop.

Also, at the end of below line there is a missing semi-colon -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(beforePath+row+afterPath+col+"]")).click()
```